# Google Play Game Services iOS giving error when launching quick match in rtmp

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, rtmp, multiplayer

I'm developing a real-time multiplayer game for Android an iOS with Google Play Game Services.

The GPG is implemented in the game as Google's documentation tells and this works well on Android. But on iOS, the game shows an error log (does not crash) when trying to automatch.

"2015-02-22 13:13:13.458 [RTMP] (Error) +[GPGRealTimeRoomMaker performPreCheck:checkDelegate:]:[main] Real-time multiplayer is not enabled for the game"

Note this error comes up when i call "[GPGRealTimeRoomMaker createRoomFromConfig:config];" 
or
"[[GPGLauncherController sharedInstance] presentRealTimeWaitingRoomWithConfig:config];"

I have this setting enabled for the iOS linked app. I also have the certificates linked up.
Signing in works well and I have fully implemented Google Play Game Services on the Android game, but on iOS i cannot proceed because of that error (the player is not found by the other 2 players on android devices"

for example if the app's name is TestGame with a bundle of com.a.b, I provided the bundle Id as com.a.b.TestGame. the .p12(APNS) certificates are also using that bundle id.

I have done a lot of troubleshooting and debugging, but cannot figure this out. I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue before. I can provide more details if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally solve my initial issue.

PROBLEM: I have a lobby screen which i call "[[GPGManager sharedInstance] signInWithClientID:GOOGLE_GAME_SERVICES_CLIENT_ID silently:NO];", and i also have a game screen that comes after the lobby screen which i call "[[GPGManager sharedInstance] signInWithClientID:GOOGLE_GAME_SERVICES_CLIENT_ID silently:NO];" again. What i had to do was replace the code in the game screen with a check if user signed in and if not call "[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];" instead!
I believe the important thing here is the check if the user is already signed in. I recall removing that check because it was crashing on the phone - little did i know it worked the whole time.
It still crashes on an actual device like the sample app, but my initial issue is resolved.